# Python 2.7.3 - ImportError: No module named PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to figure PyInstaller out for the past couple of hours, and I keep getting this error.  I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction as to how I can fix this.  I'm using PyInstaller 2.0

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You might get higher-quality answers if you add to your question a little bit about how you are using PyInstaller and the full error message.

Comment: How did you install PyInstaller? What platform are you on? Do you have multiple different Python installations? (If you're on a Mac, and you installed Python, you have multiples.)

Comment: I installed PyInstaller by extracting the files and running configure.py.  I'm on Windows 7 (64-bit) and I have Python 2.7 and 3.2 currently installed.

Comment: Actually, when I ran configure.py the same thing happened.  I got an ImportError saying that there's no module called PyInstaller.  It had no trouble loading the other modules, though.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding this to your python code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
```

Comment: This should truly be a comment.

Comment: @bernie not as long as if it's the actual answer, huh?

Comment: Okay, somehow I managed to get PyInstaller to run, but the dist folder that it created for my program doesn't have an exe file inside.  However, there's a .spec file in the folder.  So, I tried running build.py with that .spec file, and the same error came back up.

Comment: K so now the error doesn't pop up anymore, but build.py seems to be doing nothing at all.  Still no executable.